# Multi-image superresolution using CNNs

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to write a program that can take multiple low-resolution images as inputs and output a high-resolution image.

My understanding is that for single-image superresolution, Convolutional Neural Networks work great. I can just take a network with just three convolution layers as described [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/an-example-of-a-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-super-resolution). I can then train the network with a huge dataset of low-res images and their corresponding high-res images (with mean-squared error cost function), and it should theoretically work.

If I want to achieve greater accuracy, though, I can gain more information about a potential high-resolution image by looking at multiple low-resolution images.

So my question is: How would I modify this neural-network based algorithm to be able to take multiple images (of the same object) as input, and output a more accurate high-resolution image as a result? I would assume this is a lot more complicated, because the multiple images might be off by a fraction of a pixel, or taken from a marginally different angle.

(Sorry if anything I said is incorrect; I know virtually nothing about this field, so any advice helps!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would assume this is a lot more complicated, because the multiple images might be off by a fraction of a pixel, or taken from a marginally different angle.

I agree with your analysis that this problem presents different challenges than single-image super-resolution.

In the single image case, we know exactly where everything should be in the output image, because it is just a higher resolution version of the input.

So why not try and extend this idea to your case? Here is how you might do that:

- Concatenate each low-res image and a low-res version of the output image as each training and test example
- For prediction concatenate each low-res image and duplicate one of them to specify the desired orientation of the output

So if you have `n` 3-channel `h x w` input images in each training example, your input shape should be `(h, w, 3*(n+1))`

This should give the network enough information to learn the correct transformation.